# AngularJS cann't access ng-click from ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularJS1.2 routing feature to partialy load some views.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/profile/personalInfo', {templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url().'profile/personalInfo' ?>', controller: personalInfo});
        $routeProvider.when('/profile/myPlaces', {templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url().'profile/myPlaces' ?>', controller: myPlaces});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/profile/personalInfo'});
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

 function personalInfo($scope, $http){
      console.log('personal info');
  }

  function myPlaces($scope, $http){
      console.log('my places');
      $scope.places = [];
      //then fill places via $http.post request
      $scope.loadMore = function(){
         console.log('clicked');
      }
  }
```

this is my parial page:

```
<div>
    <h1>My Places Page</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="place in places">
        <a href="" ng-click="loadMore()">load more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The routing had been done successfully, but when i click the link to call `loadMore`, then this error appear in the console `undefined is not a function`.
What is the problem and how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a soluation, but i'm not sure if this soluation is the optimal but at least it solved the problem.
I created a custom directive as the following

```
app.directive('whenClicked', function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attr) {
            var raw = elm[0];
            angular.element(raw).bind('click', function() {
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        };
    });
```

and then from the partial page you can call the directive

```
<div>
    <h1>My Places Page</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="place in places">
        <a href="" when-clicked>load more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need a basic directive for the click event that you will use in multiple apps, then this works.  Otherwise it's a controller function, as part of the mvc structure.  The controller handles the change between the view (clicking) and data (model).

Answer (score 0):

Make it a controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',function myPlaces($scope, $http){
  console.log('my places');
  $scope.places = [];
  //then fill places via $http.post request
  $scope.loadMore = function(){
     console.log('clicked');
  }
 });
```

Comment: what is `OverviewCtrl`? can you provide more details.

Comment: My fault. You have to rename it to myPlaces ofcourse. I highly recommend to give a look to http://www.egghead.io and the angular docs for further information.

Also, have you worked through the tutorial?